# Warning: validateDOMNesting(...): <a> cannot appear as a descendant of <a> react js/cordova application

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am making a react js application. Within this application i understand i have a tag inside a tag like so:

```html
<a><a></a></a>
```

I have located the issue in hand as you can see in these pictures. But I am unable to fix the problem. If anyone could give me a hand i would be very thankful.

[image]

The commented out code is where i am having my issue. As you can see i have a Link tag and inside that Link tag i have a Dropdown tag. The Dropdown is causing the issue but it is needed for my application.

[image]

Edit:

I understand an a-tag cannot live inside another a-tag, i have tried a few different ways to to get the full use of the dropdown and the link. As you can see in these new pictures i am trying to get the card to be a link to a group while also having a dropdown with two options, Edit and Delete.

This is what the card looks like, the three dots is the dropdown menu. when this card is clicked it brings me to the "/group/manage/" page.

[image]

This is what the card looks like with the dropdown menu clicked.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I recommend restructuring your component in a way similar to this:

```
<Card>
    <Link>
        {mainContent}
    </Link>
    <Dropdown>
        {dropDownItems}
    </Dropdown>
</Card>
```

Then use CSS to position the dropdown to the top right, on top of the main content.

Comment: I get that an a-tag can't live inside another a-tag, any chance my edit has made it any clearer to what i am trying to accomplish?

Comment: I see what you are trying to do! I changed my answer completely to a recommendation of restructuring. I hope it helps!